# Monty Hall Change in Problem Suggestion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, monty-hall

So, Let's say we have three doors and three guests in our show. A car is behind one door. The other two doors have goats . Please note.. I am **not** asking about the original Monty Hall problem here. This is another problem (but eventually it might be equivalent to the original one).

Each guest picks a different door. and the host opens one losing door and says goodbye to one contestant.Then He asks each of the remaining guests if they would like to switch.

**Q1** What is winning probability of each of the remaining guests if they decide to switch?

**Q2** If both have to switch doesn't that mean that the computed probabilities are useless?

- **NOTE** I am aware that we have two events which **aren't** disjoint here

Event A : Car is behind the losing door or first remaining guest's choice

Event B : Car is behind the losing door or second remaining guest's choice

and each has 2/3 chance to win. So, the sum here isn't 1

So, eventually.. If the answer is to **Switch** or **NOT** , doesn't it mean that we have same probability for the remaining doors.
Thanks.. please **give time for discussion** and don't down vote for the question if it's against your mathematical beliefs. I am suggesting a new problem here, so be open to other's ideas :)

Comment: This is not a discussion site.  And as you say, this is not the standard version where (importantly) the host cannot open a door that a guest has chosen, so the answer is different

Comment: Your suggested problem might even help it finally "click" for some people, since one can identify the $1/3$ cases that would have been thrown out in your game but is added to the "switch-to-win" case in the original Monty Hall Problem. Monty Hall is notoriously difficult to explain due to intuition blocks!

Comment: Now assume that Monty has a preference between the contestants. Before the three contestants chose, he had decided ahead which one of any possible pair choosing the two goats he will throw out. Does that make a difference? And if you are a candidate and you know his preference, does that make a difference?

Comment: @gnasher729 If I bribe Monty to exclude me from getting out regardless of my choice, isn't that case equivalent to the original problem with one exception that we have two guests to decide? and how come here they have 50/50 chance to win but with the original problem it's not 50/50 ?

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, both remaining doors have $\frac 12$, so there is no advantage to switching.

To compute the probabilities directly, consider the contestant who has chosen $\#1$.  Initially, there were three states each with probability $\frac 13$, according to whichever door contained the prize.  Let's at Monty opens $\#3$ and shows it is empty, removing one of the states.

Conditioned on the state in which the prize really is behind door $\#1$, the probability that Monty would have opened $\#3$ is $\frac 12$ (since nothing distinguishes doors $1,3$).  It follows that the probability that the prize is being $\#1$ AND Monty opens $\#3$ is $\frac 13\times \frac 12=\frac 16$.Thus the conditional probability that the door is behind $\#1$, conditioned on Monty opening $\#3$ is $$\frac {1/6}{1/3}=\frac 12$$.

The same computation applies to the state in which the prize is behind door $\#2$ (just switch the rolls of $\#1$ and $\#2$ in the earlier computation).

Thus, as expected, there is no advantage gained from switching (though it doesn't hurt).

To stress:  In this version of the game, nothing distinguishes the two unopened doors. That's what I meant in the, terse, initial statement that symmetry instantly implied the answer was $\frac 12$. In the standard version, the two unopened doors are *very* different, since Monty would never open the door the contestant had selected.

As is often the case in problems like these, it is very easy to simulate the situation.  Worth doing as intuition often lets one down.

Comment: So, when someone else is there.. Don't switch. But when you're alone Switch?

Comment: This game is entirely different from the standard game, since Monty might open the one you picked.  You can not use this game to analyze the standard one, as the rules are critically different.

Comment: In your invented game, it does not matter whether you switch or not.  (What happened to your other recent questions on this subject?)

Comment: As another variant of the standard game, one that strains intuition a bit, suppose that Monty (as usual) will open one of the two unselected doors but in this variant suppose he has no idea where the prize is.  Thus, there is a $\frac 13$ chance that he reveals the prize (at which point, the contestant loses and the game is over).  In this variant, there is no advantage to switching.  Verifying this is a useful exercise.

Comment: @lulu But I can say.. Let's put two imaginary friends there and don't switch :)
You know what I'm trying to say here that.. it's just not reasonable for me when I compare

Comment: @lulu A slight remark : In the standard version, the chosen door can NOT be opened. If the new player has no information , the probility to win is $\frac{1}{2}$ for him/her. This has been discussed in a now deleted post. He/she will make the "good" decision as often as the "bad" decision.

Comment: @Peter, of course.  That is what I said.  Or at least what I meant to say.  Do I have a typo somewhere?

Comment: @lulu A strange variation where the showmaster can open the door with the car. But I agree this is a useful additional exercise.

Comment: @NidalJ  Stop.  this game is not the same as the standard game because the rules are radically different.  That makes the conclusion different.  Don't start wildly throwing out new ideas you obviously haven't thought through, as you did in your two prior questions.

Comment: @Peter  for me, it highlights the point that the advantage derives from Monty's knowledge.  He avoided a certain door, either by chance or because he knew it had the prize.  You can use that to your advantage.  If he has no knowledge, then his actions are random and you can't learn anything from them.

Comment: @lulu "since Monty might open the one you picked"

Comment: @Peter In that phrase, I am speaking of the variant the OP has defined.  In this variant, Monty won't ever reveal the prize, but he can choose the door you selected (which eliminates you as a contestant but which does not end the game for the other two players).

Comment: @lulu But new ideas are good :).. for example, let's say you prove that my problem is equivalent to the original one, that would be a great achievement.
Don't worry, I wont post more about the problem. I've said everything in my mind :)

Comment: By the way, many variants of Monty hall are discussed in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Peter Is this one of them?

Comment: @lulu "since Monty might open the one you picked"
but I have two imaginary friends, and one of them is always unlucky and gets out :)

Answer (score 1):

In that case it wouldn't be better to switch for any player, and if you think it should just because the answer in Monty Hall game, it's because you have not understood why the Monty Hall works, so let's start from it.

At first each option is equally likely to have the prize, as we don't have any information that can tell us that one is easier to have it than other. We can therefore represent the total probability $1$ as the total area of the rectangle below, which in turn is divided in three other sections of the same size each  (three parts of $1/3$ probability), corresponding to the three possible locations of the car.

[image]

Now, according to the rules of the game the host knows the locations of the contents and must reveal a losing door from the two that the player did not pick. That means that when the player is incorrect, the host is forced to reveal specifically the only other incorrect one, while when the player is the winner the host can reveal any of the other two; we don't know which in advance, they are equally likely for us, because both would be losing ones in that case.

So, if for example the player starts selecting door 1, adding the corresponding revelations in the rectangle above we get:

[image]

As you see, we have got a disparity. The rectangle that represents when the host reveals door 2 and the car in in door 1 is only half as big as the rectangle in which the host reveals that same door 2 but the prize in in door 3. That means that winning by switching is twice as likely as winning by staying.

If you prefer, you can get the new probabilities applying rule of three. The scenarios when the host opens door 2 are the green rectangles. From them, the case when door 1 has the prize originally had $1/6$ chance and the other had $1/3$ chance. Since the total probabilities must sum $1$, with rule of three you get that which originally had $1/6$ has $1/3$ at this point, and which originally had $1/3$ has $2/3$ at this point.  Similar reasoning is applied to when the host reveals door 3, and you can draw by yourself the rest of the diagrams representing when the contestant starts selecting each of the other doors.

In the long run the sample proportion tends to approach the actual probability, so if you repeated the game $900$ times, in about $300$ the car should tend to appear in each door. Now, if you always start choosing door 1, from the $300$ in which the correct is door 1 only in about $150$ the host would reveal door 2 and in the other $150$ he would reveal door 3. Instead, in all the $300$ games that the car is in door 2 the host would reveal door 3, and in all the $300$ that the car is in door 3 the host would reveal door 2.

That disparity does not occur in the game you proposed. No player was given the privilege of always advancing to the second part. With no further information, we can only assume that the host is equally likely to reveal any of the two losing doors in any case, so the diagram would be:

[image]

Here, once the host discards a specific door and so the corresponding player is eliminated, only two rectangles remain as possibilities, but this time they are of the same size, so at that point each represents $1/2$ chance to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I do find your problem interesting! The main questions you ask seem to be:

1. Does it matter if they switch or not in your game?
2. How exactly is your game equivalent to or different from the original Monty Hall Problem?

So in effect, we have to strategies on the table to try out in either game:

- Switching
- Not switching

### Breakdown of your game

We assume that placing the car and the host opening an (available) door is performed uniformly at random. Then we have:

**Switching**
$$
P(win)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ other)=\frac 23\cdot\frac 12=\frac 13\\
P(lose)=P(right\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ either)=\frac13\cdot \frac22=\frac13\\
P(thrown\ out)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ yours)=\frac 23\cdot\frac 12=\frac 13
$$
**Not switching**
$$
P(win)=P(right\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ either)=\frac 13\cdot\frac22=\frac13\\
P(lose)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ other)=\frac 23\cdot\frac 12=\frac 13\\
P(thrown\ out)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ yours)=\frac 23\cdot\frac 12=\frac 13
$$

### Breakdown of Monty Hall

**Switching**
$$
P(win)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ other)=\frac 23\cdot1=\frac 23\\
P(lose)=P(right\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ either)=\frac13\cdot \frac22=\frac13
$$
**Not switching**
$$
P(win)=P(right\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ either)=\frac13\cdot \frac22=\frac13\\
P(lose)=P(wrong\ door)\cdot P(host\ opens\ other)=\frac 23\cdot1=\frac 23
$$

So maybe you can see, that in your game two things can happen when you chose a wrong door to begin with:

- You stay in the game
- You are thrown out

The "You are thrown out" case in your version is converted to a "You are guaranteed to win if switching" in the original problem. Hence it shifts an extra $1/3$ onto the winning-by-switching case and also changes the denominator of cases where you stay in the game.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to show that moment when both problems are the same.
For that, I need help from two (imaginary :) ) friends in the original problem. When I am asked to switch or not, I imagine my friends Bob and Charley. They were there from the beginning. Poor Bob is always in front o the losing door. At that moment, I wouldn't switch according to the probabilities in the second problem :)

Comment: @NidalJ Your problem is not equivalent to the original problem. Do you think it would be in some sense? Or are you adding new conditions?

Comment: I know. But, what if i bribe Monty not to let me out from the beginning :) aren't they the same?

Comment: @NidalJ Yes, then they are - then they are both "The Original Monty Hall Problem". But notice how all probabilities have changed, since $$P(host\ open\ yours)=0\\P(host\ opens\ either)=P(host\ opens\ other)=1$$ now.